# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state while inserting values into database

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, sql-server-2005

the following code is a part of my application while executing this i am getting invalid cursor state error, i am using sql server 2005 and jsp and html.

```
<%
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:disman");
  java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
  stmt.executeUpdate("insert into earthquake(area,rictor,eqz,kms,city,state,date1,time,population,carea,farea,pland,animals,humanlife,animalsloss,sinjury,mininjury)values('"+area+"','"+rictor+"','"+eqz+"','"+kms+"','"+city+"','"+state+"','"+date1+"','"+time+"','"+population+"','"+carea+"','"+farea+"','"+pland+"','"+animals+"','"+humanlife1+"','"+animalsloss1+"','"+sinjury1+"','"+mininjury1+"')");
String items[]=request.getParameterValues("cmbitem");
   int i=0;
  ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select * from earthquake");
  int eid=rs1.getInt("eid");
   while(i < items.length)
   { String itm=items[i];
  if(itm.equals("water bottle"))
   {
 int totallits=rempop*3;
 int totalbottles=(int)(totallits/litperbottle);
 stmt.executeUpdate("insert into eq_requirement(eid,items,noitems) values('"+eid+"','"+itm+"','"+totalbottles+"'");
i++;
break;
   }
  else if(itm.equals("nurses"))
  {
 int totaldoctors=(int)(sinjury/10);
 totaldoctors=(int)(totaldoctors+(mininjury/20));
int totalnurses=totaldoctors*2;
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into eq_requirement(eid,items,noitems) values('"+eid+"','"+itm+"','"+totalnurses+"'");
i++;
break;
   }
  else
   {
    out.println("<script language=javascript>alert('Earth Quake Details not added');</script>");
 }
   }
   out.println("<script language=javascript>alert('Earth Quake Details Added Successfully');</script>");
 con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
  {
       out.println(e);
      }   
}//if update==true
}//if post event
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your insert statements you miss the end braces ,

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into eq_requirement(eid,items,noitems)
     values('"+eid+"','"+itm+"','"+totalbottles+"')");
```

And also here ,

```
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into eq_requirement(eid,items,noitems) 
values('"+eid+"','"+itm+"','"+totalnurses+"')");
```

Update:

```
ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery("select * from earthquake");
while(rs1.next){
  int eid=rs1.getInt("eid");
}
```

Hope this helps

<sub>**Side Note:** Best way to avoid sql mistakes is printing your query before execution and also run them in the sql developer</sub>

Comment: Sir Thanks for your reply, but still it is giving same error.

Comment: might the be column names have you checked the columns in the table ?

Comment: I checked column names they are correct as in table. one more thing is that ** stmt.executeUpdate("insert into earthquake(area,rictor,eqz,kms,city,state,date1,time,population,carea,farea,pland,animals,humanlife,animalsloss,sinjury,mininjury)values('"+area+"','"+rictor+"','"+eqz+"','"+kms+"','"+city+"','"+state+"','"+date1+"','"+time+"','"+population+"','"+carea+"','"+farea+"','"+pland+"','"+animals+"','"+humanlife1+"','"+animalsloss1+"','"+sinjury1+"','"+mininjury1+"')");**    This is working properly.

Comment: Have you specified any constraints on them ? i mean the column in the database

Comment: Where have you executed the query you mentioned in the comment? and in which line you get the error now?

Comment: If my answer helped you . feel free to upvote and accept the answer . it might help others